# Resize and Compress image to byte array without saving the new image

Tags: vb.net

The image is first resized, compressed and then saved on disk as "Preview.jpg" and then it is opened to convert into byte array. The code works fine but I cannot figure out how to do it without saving the image on disk.

Here is the code:

```
Public Function GetThumb_Preview(ByVal sourceImg As String) As Byte()

    Dim jgpEncoder As ImageCodecInfo = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    Dim myEncoder As System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality
    Dim myEncoderParameters As New EncoderParameters(1)
    Dim myEncoderParameter As New EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50&)
    myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter

    Dim myBitmap As New Bitmap(sourceImg)

    Dim oWidth As Integer = myBitmap.Width
    Dim oHeight As Integer = myBitmap.Height

    Dim aspectRatio As Double = oHeight / oWidth

    Dim thumbWidthDouble As Double = 200
    Dim thumbHeightDouble As Double = Math.Round(thumbWidthDouble * aspectRatio)

    Dim thumbWidth As Integer = CInt(thumbWidthDouble)
    Dim thumbHeight As Integer = CInt(thumbHeightDouble)

    Dim myThumb As New Bitmap(myBitmap, thumbWidth, thumbHeight)

    Dim targetPreviewPath As String = "E:\Preview.jpg"

    myThumb.Save(targetPreviewPath, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters)

    Dim myImage As Image = Image.FromFile(targetPreviewPath)

    Dim imgByteArray As Byte() = Nothing

    'Image to byte[]      
    Dim imgMemoryStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    myImage.Save(imgMemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    imgByteArray = imgMemoryStream.GetBuffer()

    Return imgByteArray

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a lot of variables to do so little.  You also have a number of objects not being disposed.  It will also return a valid Byte array only when the resulting byte data is less than the buffer size.  It works *in this case* because you are resizing to 200x and reducing quality.

I didnt test if I collapsed all those variables correctly, but should be very close.  More important is disposing things you create, and getting the all the Bytes for the return:

```
Dim jgpEncoder As ImageCodecInfo = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg)
Dim myEncoder As System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder = 
          System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality
Dim myEncoderParameters As New EncoderParameters(1)
Dim myEncoderParameter As New EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50&)
myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter

Dim imgByteArray As Byte()

Using myBitmap As New Bitmap(sourceImg)    ' i guess this is from file

    Dim aspectRatio As Double = myBitmap.Height / myBitmap.Width

    ' USING for disposable objects
    Using myThumb As New Bitmap(myBitmap, 200, 
                                CInt(Math.Round(200 * aspectRatio))),
        ms As New MemoryStream

        ' encode image to memstream
        myThumb.Save(ms, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters)

        ' rewind and get ALL bytes for the new image
        ms.Position = 0
        imgByteArray = ms.ToArray

    End Using
End Using           ' dispose

Return imgByteArray
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out all these issues. I am actually a habitual programmer, this is not my field, that is why my codes are always so unprofessional. So, you said it is necessary to dispose off the object, why so? does it affect memory or something else too? and other than "Using", can I dispose off an object by setting it to "nothing"?

Comment: a NET Bitmap for example creates a Win GDI+ bitmap which is not something NET can clean up. .Dispose tells your managed `bmp` object that you are done with it, so it can release that resource.  Just setting to Nothing allows NET to garbage collect your bmp, but it **cant** do anything with the 'inner' resources created.  USING blocks automatically dispose and release resources at the end. your code would leak resources in a loop.  The big problem was GetBuffer vs ToArray.  Your code would not work for someone else with larger thumbs.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting it now. Seems like I need to make amendments to my rest of the code too. I will test the code you provided above, and will rate it. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1):

You could save it to a stream and load it from there

```
    Using Str As New MemoryStream
        myThumb.Save(Str, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters)
        myImage = Image.FromStream(Str)
    End Using
```