# Save image from picturebox - VB

Tags: vb.net, screenshot, system.drawing

Im trying to combine two codes (button2 and button3). I want when Button2 is clicked the image from picturebox1 to be compressed (button3 code) and saved without dialog, just save without asking. Here is the code(button2 code works, but is giving dialog, button3 gives an error).

THE ERROR: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
Additional information: Parameter is not valid.  LINE: Dim bmp1 As New Bitmap("c:\TestPhoto.jpg")

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim bounds As Rectangle
    Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim graph As Graphics
    bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
    screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
    graph.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
    PictureBox1.Image = screenshot
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim savefiledialog1 As New SaveFileDialog
    savefiledialog1.Title = "Save File"
    savefiledialog1.FileName = "*.jpg"
    savefiledialog1.Filter = "Jpeg |*.jpg"
    If savefiledialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        PictureBox1.Image.Save(savefiledialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'Private Sub VaryQualityLevel()
    ' Get a bitmap. 
    Dim bmp1 As New Bitmap("c:\TestPhoto.jpg")
    Dim jgpEncoder As ImageCodecInfo = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    Dim myEncoder As System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality
    Dim myEncoderParameters As New EncoderParameters(1)

    Dim myEncoderParameter As New EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50&)
    myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter
    bmp1.Save("c:\TestPhotoQualityFifty.jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters)

    myEncoderParameter = New EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100&)
    myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter
    bmp1.Save("c:\TestPhotoQualityHundred.jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters)

    ' Save the bitmap as a JPG file with zero quality level compression.
    myEncoderParameter = New EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 0&)
    myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter
    bmp1.Save("c:\TestPhotoQualityZero.jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters)

End Sub 'VaryQualityLevel

Private Function GetEncoder(ByVal format As ImageFormat) As ImageCodecInfo

    Dim codecs As ImageCodecInfo() = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders()

    Dim codec As ImageCodecInfo
    For Each codec In codecs
        If codec.FormatID = format.Guid Then
            Return codec
        End If
    Next codec
    Return Nothing

End Function
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: care to share what and where that error is, or shall we guess?

Comment: Dude, don't add it as a comment - edit it into your question.

Comment: ...and where (what line?)

Comment: (we know) make sure that file actually exists, and it would be a good idea to move it to something like `C:\Temp`  ... I thought I [recognized that code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24760513/1070452) complete with jpg/jgp typo

Comment: File exists, changed to temp. Same error

Comment: check also if it is a valid JPG image ...or just use another "JGP" image.

Comment: Tried another image - no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand from your question, you have to save the captured ScreenShot cliking Button_1 without showing dialoge by clicking Button_2 after exicuting code under Button_3. If it like so --

follow this way.........

At first **From your code just free out the** `Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap` from Button_1 Sub and paste it as generic for document.

Secondly **Just copy the following Sub.**

```
Public Sub SaveImage(filename As String, image As Image, Encoder As ImageCodecInfo, EncParam As EncoderParameter)
    Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, filename & ".jpg")
    Dim mySource As New Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height)
    Dim grfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(mySource)
    grfx.DrawImageUnscaled(image, Point.Empty)
    grfx.Dispose()
    mySource.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    mySource.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Thirdly **Leave completely the code under Button_2 and cut & paste the code under Button_3 under Button_2**

Forthly chnge your Code like this.

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Private Sub VaryQualityLevel()
    ' Get a bitmap. 
    Dim bmp1 As New Bitmap(screenshot)
    Dim jgpEncoder As ImageCodecInfo = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    Dim myEncoder As System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality
    Dim myEncoderParameters As New EncoderParameters(1)

    Dim myEncoderParameter As New EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50&)
    myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter
    'your Code....// bmp1.Save("c:\TestPhotoQualityFifty.jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters)
    '// Call the above Sub
     SaveImage("C:\Users\User\Desktop\TestPhotoQualityFifty.jpg", bmp1, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameter)

    myEncoderParameter = New EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100&)
    myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter


    'your Code....// bmp1.Save("c:\TestPhotoQualityFifty.jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters)
    '// Call the above Sub
    SaveImage("C:\Users\User\Desktop\TestPhotoQualityFifty.jpg", bmp1, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameter)

    ' Save the bitmap as a JPG file with zero quality level compression.
    myEncoderParameter = New EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 0&)
    myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter


    'your Code....// bmp1.Save("c:\TestPhotoQualityFifty.jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters)
    '// Call the above Sub
    SaveImage("C:\Users\User\Desktop\TestPhotoQualityFifty.jpg", bmp1, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameter)

End Sub 'VaryQualityLevel
```

**Rest of all your code remains.**

**And Now Done!**

Here is the sample Image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To Save the Visible part of a pictureBox without asking dialog ...

**Just Copy paste the following Sub to your code**

```
Public Sub SaveImage(filename As String, image As Image)
    Dim path As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, filename & ".jpg")
    Dim mySource As New Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height)
    Dim grfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(mySource)
    grfx.DrawImageUnscaled(image, Point.Empty)
    grfx.Dispose()
    mySource.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    mySource.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Then **add this code under Button or other exicutable place.**

```
    Dim x As Integer = PictureBox1.Width
    Dim y As Integer = PictureBox1.Height
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(x, y)
    PictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bm, New Rectangle(0, 0, x, y))

    PictureBox1.Image = bm

'// Save The Visible Part of PictureBox Only (.....Cropped.....)
    SaveImage("C:\Users\User\Desktop\1" & ".jpg", bm)

'// Save The image in PictureBox in its Original size.
    SaveImage("C:\Users\User\Desktop\1" & ".jpg", PictureBox1.image)
```