# Saving Image into memory stream Error

Tags: vb.net, gdi+, memorystream, oledbcommand

I'm trying to:

1) Scan an image and insert it to a memorystream.

2) Show it in picturebox1.

3) Read picturebox1 image into memorystream and save it to oledb.

here's my code :

1st) Scanning by WIA Dialog and inserting image to memorystream then showing it in picturebox1:

```
 Try

   Dim CD As New WIA.CommonDialog

   Dim F As WIA.ImageFile = CD.ShowAcquireImage(WIA.WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType)

   If F IsNot Nothing Then

            Dim MStream As IO.MemoryStream = Nothing
            Try
                'Convert the raw scanner output into a byte array
                Dim ImageBytes() As Byte = DirectCast(F.FileData.BinaryData, Byte())
                'Read the image data bytes into a MemoryStream
                MStream = New IO.MemoryStream(ImageBytes)
                PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(MStream)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("An error occurred:  " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End Try
            If MStream IsNot Nothing Then MStream.Dispose()
   End If

  Catch ex As Exception
      MsgBox(ex.message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
  End Try
```

This is working perfectly.

The problem is coming,

2nd) Reading image from picturebox1 into new memorystream then save it to oledb:

```
If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.ConnectionString = connstring
        conn.Open()

            'Reading image from picturebox1 and then insert it to a new memorystream.
            Dim arrImage() As Byte
            Dim myMs As New IO.MemoryStream
            PictureBox1.Image.Save(myMs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            arrImage = myMs.GetBuffer

            'Now save image to oledb from the memorystream.
            Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO Guestinfo ([IDImage]) VALUES (@IDImage)"
            Dim command As New OleDbCommand
            With command
                .CommandText = query
                .Parameters.Add("@IDImage", OleDb.OleDbType.Binary).Value = arrImage
                .Connection = conn
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            MsgBox("Saved Successfully!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            conn.Close()
            ListView1.Items.Clear()
            loadlistview()
            Me.Close()
 End If
```

Error is on this line :

```
PictureBox1.Image.Save(myMs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

I might see that this error because during the scanning process we were converting the image into byte array to put it into memorystream, but while reading process we were trying to read the picturebox image as Jpeg into memorystream.

I can see it's complicated for me as a beginner in visualbasic any help would be appreciated.

Comment: But what is the error message?

Comment: A Generic Error occurred in GDI+ @Steve

Comment: 2 problems, after you save to the MS, you need to reset the Position to 0, then use ToArray not GetBuffer.  You should also be disposing those streams.

Comment: I'm sorry @Plutonix but can you tell me how, i'm little newbie...

Comment: [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24760513/1070452)  It may not solve the error you are getting because it is a generic one that covers many problems, but those things need to be fixed

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but the [docs for `Image.FromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) say that the stream must be kept open for the lifetime of the `Image`, but in your 1st code block you are calling `MStream.Dispose()`.  You could try removing that line.

Comment: Thank you @Plutonix for your effort, i fixed it as you told me, but as you said it's Generic, those fixing wont solve the error.

Comment: Aside from the memstream possibility Mark mentions, it could also be the format.  What format does the scanner return?  Use debug maybe to examine the image properties to see, if not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation for [`Image.FromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the stream must be kept open for the lifetime of the `Image`, but you are disposing of the stream in this line:

```
If MStream IsNot Nothing Then MStream.Dispose()
```

Try removing that line from your first code block.

I suppose the `MemoryStream` should be disposed of at some point, but perhaps the `PictureBox` and `Image` classes will take care of that for you.  Otherwise, you may have to add a `Dispose` call when the form is closed.