# Embedded base64String for images is to long for large images?

Tags: vb.net, tinymce, base64

I am embedding a base64String into Tinymce to display images:

```
<img src="blob:https://path/871bf236-3bae-472c-9f02-0bd3be19a435" alt="Desert.jpg" width="300" height="75" />
```

It works for small images but when it comes to large images it doesn't work and I am guessing its because the URL containing the base64String for large images hits the limit for URL browser length which I believe is around 2000 characters. Wanted to see if there was a way to shorten my base64String?

```
'File path of the attachment 
DIM filePath = C:\path\solutions\Attachments\1\1726014c-7a2d-41b8-a79e-2acec1e8c7e0

'Converted base64String path 
DIM base64URLPath = ToBase64String( ConvertToUrl(filePath)).toString

'Converts the path to a base64String
Public Function ToBase64String(filePath As String) As String
        Dim aImage = New Bitmap(filePath)
        Using stream = New IO.MemoryStream
            Using img As Image = Image.FromFile(filePath)
                If img.RawFormat.Equals(Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) Then
                    aImage.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                ElseIf img.RawFormat.Equals(Imaging.ImageFormat.Png) Then
                    aImage.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
                ElseIf img.RawFormat.Equals(Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon) Then
                    aImage.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon)
                End If
            End Using
            Return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray)
        End Using
    End Function

  'Gets the full file path 
  Public Function ConvertToUrl(filePath As String) As String
        Dim uri = New Uri(filePath).LocalPath
        Dim converted = uri
        Return converted.ToString()
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this post I fixed the issue: [Resize and Compress image to byte array without saving the new image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756836/resize-and-compress-image-to-byte-array-without-saving-the-new-image). The ToBase64String was the only function changed and now it looks like:

```
'Converts the path to a base64String
 Public Function ToBase64String(filePath As String) As String
        Dim aImage = New Bitmap(filePath)
        Dim aspectRatio As Double = aImage.Height / aImage.Width
        Dim imgThumb = New Bitmap(aImage, 200, CInt(Math.Round(200 * aspectRatio)))
        Using stream = New IO.MemoryStream
            Using img As Image = Image.FromFile(filePath)
                If img.RawFormat.Equals(Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg) Then
                  imgThumb.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                ElseIf img.RawFormat.Equals(Imaging.ImageFormat.Png) Then
                   imgThumb.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
                ElseIf img.RawFormat.Equals(Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon) Then
                   imgThumb.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Icon)
                End If
            End Using
            Return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray)
        End Using
    End Function
```